# Force users to have latest android app version

Tags: java, android, mysql

Is it possible to check on startup of an Android app whether the user has the latest version of it and force him to update if he has not? Or at least checkt whether there is a new version and tell him, that the app only will work again when he downloads and installs the update?

Background is that I have an app that needs to communicate with a server. When I change something in the interface between server and client I want to assure that the client has the latest version.

Is there any native way to do this? Or do I have to check this on my own?

Is this only accessible if you have a mysql database? is it possible to do this with just plain text on a webpage and have it checked with the current app version?

Comment: Good question! Welcome to SO!

Comment: NIce question to start with. +1

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is it possible to do this with just
>   plain text on a webpage and have it
>   checked with the current app version?

That's what I would do:

Checking latest version on your server, in a text file:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String latestVersion = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
latestVersion = str.toString();
```

and then compare it to the installed version:

```
private String getSoftwareVersion() {
    try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionName;//EDIT: versionCode would be better
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Package name not found", e);
    };
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but where would you put the first code? I'm new to android-server connection.

Comment: You can choose to do that daily, to do that on each one of your application launch, on each time you get an error from your webservice, or you don't get the correctly formated answer ( so your code has certainly changed) it depend, there is no right answer.. Bu I would say the last one is the best.

Comment: No i meant where do i put the HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String latestVersion = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
latestVersion = str.toString();

Comment: also could you be so kind and add in like //hashmarks
to the places where i need to change the variables for my specific server and such. Thanks!

Comment: This solution has some issues, as I am trying to investigate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835419/how-to-force-update-on-an-app-when-backend-changes-requires-an-updated-app