# How would i know my latest version of Android app has been updated to all installed users?

Tags: android

I have recently updated my Android app from Google Developer Console. I have updated my app from 1.1 version to 1.2 version. But how i would know that an update notification has gone to all active install user of my app.

Whether i need to write some code or is there any option available in Google Developer Console...

Please help me out , i need this essentially.

Comment: From experience, you will *never* have all users on the latest version. Some users never update their apps; you'll always have a few lingering old versions out there. One thing you can do is have a server-side check that enforces a minimum version number and disable the app if it doesn't match the latest.

Comment: What about the offline apps who don't need any to the access to server side.

Comment: I would ask why you need your users to be on the latest version. If it's necessary for a new feature, then just only enable the feature based on the version number. If it's an offline app, then it should be even less relevant whether or not they're on the latest version.

Comment: Why i am saying because the install user needs the latest version of the app.... they are always contacting me when we will get the update...

Comment: If they care about updates then they'll check for it, and you shouldn't have to worry about it. Unless they've disabled notifications, they'll get a notification from the Play Store about any available app updates.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, the only way to tell is by day to day statistics from the google console to know how many have updated to your new version.

Go to statistics windows, then underneath the first graph there should be an option to display Active Installs by App Version.

Comment: Ahh yes , there are various option available in Google Play Developer Console.... Active Install , Daily Install , Daily Uninstall etc but how the older version user to know that their has been updated to latest version .....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619972/force-users-to-have-latest-android-app-version?rq=1 could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Even if all your users update the app, there may be backup copies. Normally, such copies are never used, but on really rare occasions something happens and... it will be really very frustrating if the backup copies get broken in the course of time.